# Where can I find UrlRoutingModule source code?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm exploring source code from http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/. But I can't find UrlRoutingModule from System.Web.Routing.

Where can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, `System.Web.Routing` isn't apart of the of the open source ASP.NET stack. Though you can view the source code on the new(ish) Reference Source site. For instance http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/Routing/UrlRoutingModule.cs is the `UrlRoutingModule` you are looking for. You could also use an disassembler like dotpeek to look at a DLL and see the source code.

Answer (score 1):

you can find UrlRoutingModule.cs here

https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/tree/master/System.Web/Routing

Answer (score -2):

Use .NET Reflector, you can see the source code.

Comment: There is no need for decompilers. It is on github